# Инкремент IP

Tags: c++

В С++ ввод начального IP и конечного IP. Необходим инкремент IP для сканирования фиксированного диапазона IP. В общем как можно изменить IP примеру 192.168.1.1 на 192.168.1.2 и так далее в С++? Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 3):

Обычно привычная запись IP-адреса в виде четырех, разделенных точками числовых значений в десятичной или шестнадцатеричной форме, переводится в самый обычный `unsigned int32` или любое другое беззнаковое целое длины 4 байта.

Для этого складывают побитно все четыре числа, учитывая сдвиг:

```
return (first << 24) | (second << 16) | (third << 8) | (fourth);
```

Для перевода обратно, делают наоборот, выделяют каждое из чисел + сдвиг + маска, в интернете есть примеры.

Имея сетевую маску и сетевой адрес, можно всегда получить первый и последний IP в заданном диапазоне. Чтобы получить первый адрес, маскируете `IP & SubnetMask`. Чтобы получить последний `IP | !SubnetMask` (`!` - знак соответствует отрицанию). И не забываем, что первый адрес в полученном диапазоне - это сеть, последний - это широковещательный адрес.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте стандартные сетевые функции  inet_addr(), inet_ntoa(), ntohl() , htonl()

Например зтот код должен (не проверял) увеличить IP в стороковой нотации.
Не забывайте про (зависит от CPU) разный порядок байт в двоичном представлении IP в сети и хосте (арифметика естественно в хостовом порядке байт).

```
#include <sys/socket.h> // не уверен, нужен ли здесь
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

...
uint32_t ip1 = (uint32_t)inet_addr("192.168.1.1");  // в двоичное в сетевом
uint32_t ip2 = ntohl(ip1);  // в порядок байт хоста
ip2++;  // арифметика
// strdup() т.к. inet_ntoa() возвращает static  char *
char *newip = strdup(inet_ntoa(htonl(ip2))); // htonl() вычисленный IP опять в сетевой
```

Ну, а классы, переопределение операций и т.п. это на ваше усмотрение (хотите людей путать, тогда вперед).

---

**update 1**

Вдогонку, вспомнил.

Осторожней с **htonl() и ntohl() в операциях сравнения**. Однажды в RedHat (не помню версию gcc) нарвался на ошибочку при gcc -O3. Там вместо вызова функции вставлялся ассемблерный код и **в if выбрасывалось преобразование типа результата**.

На всякий случай при работе с диапазонами IP присваивайте результат вызовов ntohl(), htonl() переменным и работайте с ними.

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо!!!

Answer (score 1):

Примерно вот так. Не гарантирую точность синтаксиса, давно не писал на плюсах.

```
char ip[MAX_IP];
strcpy(ip, "192.168.1.1");
byte x1,x2,x3,x4;
sscanf(ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", &x1,&x2,&x3,&x4);
sprintf(ip, "%d.%d.%d.%d", x1,x2,x3,x4 + 1);
```

Здесь изложена суть, по хорошему нужно оформить адрес в класс, для которого определить операторы инкремента, сравнения и т.п.

Comment: спасибо, а в С# этот же код подойдет?

Comment: там scanf-а нет, придется разбирать строку по другому. вариантов - множество: через string.Split, регулярные выражения, какой-нибудь Reader